# How do I plot more than one set of bars per axis on a bar plot in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I currently use the `align=’edge’` parameter and positive/negative widths in `pyplot.bar()` to plot the bar data of one metric to each axis. However, if I try to plot a second set of data to one axis, it covers the first set. Is there a way for `pyplot` to automatically space this data correctly?

```
lns3 = ax[1].bar(bucket_df.index,bucket_df.original_revenue,color='c',width=-0.4,align='edge')
lns4 = ax[1].bar(bucket_df.index,bucket_df.revenue_lift,color='m',bottom=bucket_df.original_revenue,width=-0.4,align='edge')
lns5 = ax3.bar(bucket_df.index,bucket_df.perc_first_priced,color='grey',width=0.4,align='edge')
lns6 = ax3.bar(bucket_df.index,bucket_df.perc_revenue_lift,color='y',width=0.4,align='edge')
```

This is what it looks like when I show the plot:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XwlOv.png]

The data shown in yellow completely covers the data in grey. I'd like it to be shown next to the grey data.

Is there any easy way to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first argument to the [`bar()`](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.bar) plotting method is an array of the x-coordinates for your bars. Since you pass the same x-coordinates they will all overlap. You can get what you want by staggering the bars by doing something like this:

```
x = np.arange(10)        # define your x-coordinates
width = 0.1              # set a width for your plots
offset = 0.15            # define an offset to separate each set of bars
fig, ax = plt.subplots() # define your figure and axes objects
ax.bar(x, y1)            # plot the first set of bars
ax.bar(x + offset, y2)   # plot the second set of bars
```

Since you have a few sets of data to plot, it makes more sense to make the code a bit more concise (assume `y_vals` is a list containing the y-coordinates you'd like to plot, `bucket_df.original_revenue`, `bucket_df.revenue_lift`, etc.). Then your plotting code could look like this:

```
for i, y in enumerate(y_vals):
    ax.bar(x + i * offset, y)
```

If you want to plot more sets of bars you can decrease the `width` and `offset` accordingly.